# SDK for Nokia 3310

Tags: sdk, nokia

I'm thinking some time about the possibilities to bring back some life to my loved **Nokia 3310** by developing some software for it. The only downside is that there is not really much information on the Internet about the subject.

I've read that there is a SDK called **Nokia PC Connectivity SDK 3.0**, but every link that I tried is very old and the download links are always broken. Searching on Google just gives results to Mallware websites and the Nokia Developer website only holds an archived forum section without file support..

Does anyone knows where I can download this SDK or has a better idea/suggestion about developing software for this dinosaur of a phone?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the offering is no longer available from the original site, thus I would not recommend using any versions available on any other site.

Anyway, the PC connectivity as far as I remember did not really enable you to develop any software for the device as such, it was used for making apps that could connect to the services of the device (such as SMS, logs etc.)

Quick internet search also suggest that the device might not even support AT commands, thus I would assume that there is no development offerings available for that old device anymore.